# Using another volume with Storage API supabase

Tags: docker, supabase

I am Self hosting Supabase, I don't know much about servers or docker, and need a little assistance in using a different volume for storage. My hosting plan requires that upgrade CPU and MEM every time I need more space.  They do however offer a resizable storage volume. I am not certain what : means.

The storage volume is mounted at `/mnt/volume-ash-1#`

Can I simply change the YML file to point to this volume?

```yaml
      # FILE_STORAGE_BACKEND_PATH: /var/lib/storage
      FILE_STORAGE_BACKEND_PATH: /mnt/volume-ash-1#  <----change here?
      TENANT_ID: stub
      # TODO: https://github.com/supabase/storage-api/issues/55
      REGION: stub
      GLOBAL_S3_BUCKET: stub
    volumes:
      ## - ./volumes/storage:/var/lib/storage
     ./volumes/storage:/mnt/volume-ash-1# <---- change here?
```

Just wonder if this even possible, or what other solution I could do and continue using Supabase's Storage API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, stop your container, copy the content of your `./volumes/storage` to the `/mnt/volume-ash-1` after that change to `/mnt/volume-ash-1:/var/lib/storage` and you are good to go. (The volume definition is: `/host/path:/path/in/container`)

And leave the `FILE_STORAGE_BACKEND_PATH: /mnt/volume-ash-1`  <----change here?  `FILE_STORAGE_BACKEND_PATH: /var/lib/storage` as it was

It should look like this:

```yaml
  FILE_STORAGE_BACKEND_PATH: /var/lib/storage
  TENANT_ID: stub
  # TODO: https://github.com/supabase/storage-api/issues/55
  REGION: stub
  GLOBAL_S3_BUCKET: stub
volumes:
  - /mnt/volume-ash-1:/var/lib/storage
```